# Git thinks I'm the wrong user

Tags: macos, git, github

I am on Mac OSX, git version `1.8.5.2 (Apple Git-48)`

I had a git submodule in a git repo that had (to my knowledge) only ever been cloned, pulled, committed, merged and pushed using one git user and rsa key.  I have many other pairs of users and keys but no others were specified in the ~/.gitconfig file.

When this submodule had the remote of `https://github`... etc.  It would allow me to commit with the correct username and email being applied but when pushing, would tell me that:

```
remote: Permission to some_username/project.git denied to user2.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/some_username/project.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

However when I removed the `https://...` remote and instead used the `git@github.com:some_username/project.git` remote, it works correctly.

Is this a bug with git or github?  Was there any other way to fix it?  Both these users have their associated rsa keys associated on their github accounts.

Comment: https doesn't use the associated ssh keys, so authentication won't be as transparent.

Comment: You got any links to how it works @JoachimIsaksson or can it only really be answered by looking into the git source?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5343146/477878 has some info even I didn't know about :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this a bug with git or github?

No: with https url, you need to add the login in the url for git to know what credential to ask for:

```
cd /path/to /your/submodule
git remote set-url origin https://yourLogin@github.com/yourLogin/yourRepo
```

An ssh url would use automatically your key (in `$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) which, if [published to your account](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys#step-3-add-your-ssh-key-to-github) (and if your account is the owner or collaborator of the GitHub repo)

Comment: The link ( stackoverflow.com/a/5343146/477878 ) @JoachimIsaksson gave above is well worth a read.