# Git thinks I'm a different user, won't give me access to github repo

Tags: git, github

I had an account on github (Mariogs37) that I've since stopped using.  In the meantime, I've created a new one (bclayman) that I'd like to start using.  I created a repo on github and ran:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/bclayman/SquashScraper.git
```

I get no error messages, and then I run:

```
git push -u origin master
```

However, I get this error message:

```
remote: Permission to bclayman/SquashScraper.git denied to Mariogs37.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/bclayman/SquashScraper.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I googled around for similar issues and came across this link:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019258/git-thinks-im-the-wrong-user
```

I followed vonC's answer's instructions (here: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/#step-3-add-your-ssh-key-to-github).  At the end of adding my SSH key to github, I got this in my terminal:

```
Hi bclayman! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

I retried pushing my local repo to github but have run into the same error.  Any idea why it still thinks I'm Mariogs37 (and thus don't have permissions to push to a repo on github owned by bclayman)?

Thanks,

bclayman

Comment: Did you update your `.gitconfig`? also check this out: http://superuser.com/questions/232373/how-to-tell-git-which-private-key-to-use

Comment: What would I update it with?  In my gitconfig, I have my email and name set up and credential has "helper = osxkeychain"

Comment: oh, just seen you're using the https URI... the above would work for the ssh one, but for changing the https user you probably want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14417827/1423333

Comment: ah, if you're using osxkeychain it probably saved the https credentials (username and password) in your keychain, so could try to delete them there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This most likely is a misunderstanding in what credentials are used for what.

GitHub offers you to use two different protocols to access your repo:

- HTTPS
- SSH

**SSH:**

This one uses the ssh keys and settings in your `~/.ssh` folder. It is used if you add a remote like this:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:bclayman/SquashScraper.git
```

**HTTPS (the one you chose):**

This one uses the https credentials that depending on your system could be stored in various places (if at all). As it seems you're using the OS X Keychain, so they are most likely stored there. The https protocol is used if you add a remote like this:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/bclayman/SquashScraper.git
```

So to get this resolved i'd open your OS X Keychain and search for https://github.com and delete all items that come up. Next time you try to push / fetch it should ask you for your username and password again.

Comment: Thank you! I've had a persistent issue with [gitbox](http://www.gitboxapp.com/) and old repos/changed usernames. Clearing those from the keychain was the fix for me.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try below?

```
git config --global user.name "bclayman"
git config --global user.email "email_addr_of_bclayman"
```

And also make sure under your `~/.ssh` folder, no ssh key related to `Mariogs37`, if any, delete them. Only keep ssh key of `bclayman`.

Comment: won't this only change the information used in git commits? the https credentials are stored elsewhere i think... and ssh credentials are in ~/.ssh/config

Comment: it changes your ~/.gitconfig file, which you should used to communicate with Github server.

Comment: my ~/.ssh has: github_rsa
github_rsa.pub
id_rsa
id_rsa.pub
known_hosts

Comment: yes, but as you added an https uri as remote none of the ssh settings are ever used as they don't apply to https

Comment: ah so should i just take the "https" off of the uri?